# ReactJs Updating state of similar property value

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I have two variable `a` and `b` in state. which are both copied one constant variable.(all are nested array).

Whenever i try to update `a`, it update `b` also, i dont know what the problem?

> See The `codesandbox` demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-maxwell-xvu5w

**Code:**

```
import React from "react";
const filterAttributes = [
  {
    name: "gender",
    searchable: false,
    search: "",
    values: ["Male", "Female", "Child", "Other"]
  },
  {
    name: "size",
    searchable: false,
    search: "",
    values: ["30", "35", "15", "55", "10"]
  },
  {
    name: "brand",
    searchable: true,
    search: "",
    values: [
      "Amazon",
      "Flipkart",
      "Apple",
      "Vivo",
      "Oppo",
      "Samsung",
      "Twitter"
    ]
  }
];

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      a: [...filterAttributes],
      b: [...filterAttributes]
    };
  }
  changeA = () => {
    let a = [...filterAttributes];
    a[0].search = "d-1--d";
    this.setState({ a: [...a] });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <pre style={{ maxWidth: "100%", overflowX: "scroll" }}>
          <div>A: {JSON.stringify(this.state.a)}</div>
          <hr />
          <div>B: {JSON.stringify(this.state.b)}</div>
        </pre>
        <button onClick={this.changeA}>Change A</button>
        <button>Change B</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let a = this.state.a;
a[0] = { ...a[0], ...{ search: "3-1--d" } };
this.setState({ a });
```

Using the spread operator we can make a copy of the object as well. Since this only shallow clones, it will only go one level deep.

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator only goes one level deep (Shallow Copying).This means that the objects in your array are still referenced. I would recommend using lodash for deep copies but also a custom way like this works:

```
this.state = {
      a: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filterAttributes)),
      b: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filterAttributes))
    };
```